# How to edit the "File Management Preferences" via command line in Centos Desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, executable

is it possible to edit the

```
File Management Preferences
```

via vi or something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but it is possible with `gconftool-2`. Just frob the values under `/apps/nautilus`; look in `gconf-editor` for details.

Comment: so do you know the name of the file that can be edited ?, these are actually "key names" via gui, the actual path is not known for the file that contains these settings.

Comment: It isn't a file. It's the settings stored in gconf.

Comment: i can see them via gui but i want to open this via gedit.

Comment: i am in nautilus >> preferences ( in gconf-editor ) and i see the settings, but where is the file for this that can be edited via text editors ?

Comment: Read the answer again.

Comment: there is no such path as `/apps/nautilus`

Comment: i am trying to create command lines to edit these settings, i do not want gui.

Comment: `gconftool-2` is a command line tool.

Comment: i see. i had no idea basically you know.

Comment: Yes, I know. But only because you didn't look.